# How to put a tooltip centered under a div?

Tags: javascript, html, css, tooltip, html-lists

How can I place the tooltip centered and directly under the red circle without Javascript? Thank you in advance! :-)

Here is an image of my problem and the marked position where it should be:

[image]

My code currently looks like this:

**HTML code:**

```
<li>
   <a class="ovm-oup_tooltip" href="#">
     <div id="ovm-oup_under_item_1" class="ovm-oup_under_item">
        <span>Text</span>
        <img src="Example_Logo.svg" alt="">
     </div>
   </a>
</li>
```

**CSS code:**

```
#ovm-oup_under ul{
  text-align: center;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
}
#ovm-oup_under li{
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 15px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.ovm-oup_under_item{
  width: 96px;
  height: 96px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
  margin: 5px 5px 35px 5px;
}

.ovm-oup_tooltip {
    position: relative;
    display: inline;
}
.ovm-oup_tooltip span {
    position: absolute;
    width: auto;
    padding: 3px 15px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background: #000000;
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    visibility: hidden;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
.ovm-oup_tooltip span:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -8px;
    width: 0; height: 0;
    border-bottom: 8px solid #000000;
    border-right: 8px solid transparent;
    border-left: 8px solid transparent;
}
.ovm-oup_tooltip:hover span {
    visibility: visible;
    margin: 0;
    top: 0%;
    left: 50%;
    z-index: 999;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One solution would be to combine [absolute placement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Positioning#Absolute_positioning) of the tooltip (relative to the parent `div`), with a [translation transformation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/translate) on the tooltip, which would achieve the required placement:

```css
/* Extracted styling to top of style sheet to show the required additions */

.ovm-oup_tooltip span {
  /* Offset the tooltip 50% from left side of parent (div) width
  and 100% from top edge of parent height */
  left: 50%;
  top: 100%;
  
  /* Pull the tooltip back 50% of it's own width, nudge the tool
  tip downward 8px to account for arrow point */
  transform: translate(-50%, 8px);
}

.ovm-oup_under_item {
  /* Allow absolute placement of children (tooltip) */
  position: relative;
}

/* Your existing styling starts here */
.ovm-oup_under_item {
  width: 96px;
  height: 96px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  margin: 5px 5px 35px 5px;
}

.ovm-oup_tooltip {
  position: relative;
  display: inline;
}

.ovm-oup_tooltip span {
  position: absolute;
  width: auto;
  padding: 3px 15px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background: #000000;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  visibility: hidden;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.ovm-oup_tooltip span:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -8px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-bottom: 8px solid #000000;
  border-right: 8px solid transparent;
  border-left: 8px solid transparent;
}

.ovm-oup_tooltip:hover span {
  visibility: visible;
  margin: 0;
  /* Remove 
  top: 0%;
  */
  left: 50%;
  z-index: 999;
}
```

```html
<a class="ovm-oup_tooltip" href="#">
  <div id="ovm-oup_under_item_1" class="ovm-oup_under_item">
    <span>Text</span>
    <img src="Example_Logo.svg" alt="">
  </div>
</a>
```

The idea here is to use `absolute` placement of the tooltip (ie the `span`), to position the top-left corner of that span at the horizontal center, and bottom edge of the parent div. The `transform` rule is then used to offset the tooltip `span` relative to it's own dimensions, to achieve the final center/baseline placement.

You can merge the additions above with your existing styling - I extracted the changes to the top of the stylesheet to clarify the additons that were made to achieve the desired result. Hope that helps!